# class is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in java.util.timertask

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to use a timer to repeat a function periodically. Now I have to pass inputs to the function, but I get the error "***activity*** is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in java.util.timertask".

What is the correct practice to pass values to the nested functions called by the timer? Examples online or on the java documentation are too vague.

below there is the skeleton of the code. any idea? also a link to a document where this problem is explained better will be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class className {
    Timer timer;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //declarations...
        initialiseInputs(args);
        new executePeriodicActivities(milliseconds); // milliseconds are in "args"
    }

    public void executePeriodicActivities(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new activity(args), 0, milliseconds);
    }

    class activity extends TimerTask { //error!
        public void run() {
            function(args)
            if(condition(args)) {timer.cancel();}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: You should get in the habit of naming your classes with uppercase letters. For two reasons: 1) It makes reading your code easier, and; 2) So people stop telling you to do it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `activity` class that takes a `long` parameter.  You can then use that value in the `run()` method.

```
class activity extends TimerTask { 
    private long milis;
    public activity(long milis) {
        this.milis = milis;
    }
    public void run() {
        function(args)
        if(condition(args)) {timer.cancel();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous inner class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class className {
    Timer timer;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //declarations...
        executePeriodicActivities(milliseconds, args); // milliseconds are in "args"
    }

    public static void executePeriodicActivities(int seconds, String[] args) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeTask() 
                                      {public void run() {
                                                  function(args)
                                                  if(condition(args)) {timer.cancel();}
                                                  }
                                       }, 0, milliseconds);
    }

}
```

or something similar

Comment: tested, it works also this one, but finally I'll use the solution of jjnguy, much easier =D. Anyway thanks for your help!